# Can't establish ssh connection with gitlab

Tags: git, ssh

I have a project on gitlab that I am trying to push a commit to. I have first cloned the project with https url, but then changed it to ssh, and then ran `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` that gave me the ssh key: I have copy pasted the key to my ssh keys in my gitlab profile, but on trying to push the commit I got a message:

> The authenticity of host 'gitlab' can't be established. RSA key
>   fingerprint is SHA256:cZiqgz2tMzLXftNIIXmQ9v+6M38xM1LzxROnDM1OJ0Q.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
>   Warning: Permanently added '07.no, 'myIpAddress' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. 
>   Permission denied (publickey).

On running `ssh -Tv git@myEmail`:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to myEmail [myIpAddress] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-9etch3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-9etch3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000
debug1: Authenticating to myEmail:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Wcsi4VBAIf2M+M62Gx16W2yCR8rbtm9yh/WiQRe707o
debug1: Host 'myEmail' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myUser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Ok so it's both warning you about a new host you are connecting to as @Rohit Poudel correctly answered but in your edit it also says "Permission denied (publickey)" which suggests the key isn't recognised by GitLab. Are you sure the repo is under your user account where you presumably also added your SSH key?

Comment: Also just to confirm, if you run `git remote -v` does it display: `origin git@gitlab.com:your_user_account/your_repo` rather than any references to `https`?

Comment: it displays git@gitlab

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

It's telling you that you've never connected to this server before. If you were expecting that, it's perfectly normal. If you're paranoid, verify the checksum/fingerprint of the key using an alternate channel. (But note that someone who can redirect your ssh connection can also redirect a web browser session.)

If you've connected to this server before from this install of ssh, then either the server has been reconfigured with a new key, or someone is spoofing the server's identity. Due to the seriousness of a man-in-the-middle attack, it's warning you about the possibility.

Either way, you have a secure encrypted channel to somebody. No one without the private key corresponding to fingerprint  can decode what you send.

The key you use to authenticate yourself is unrelated... you wouldn't want to send authentication information to a fraudulent server who might steal it, and so you should not expect any changes depending on whether you're going to use a passphrase or private key to login. You simply haven't gotten that far in the process yet.

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried to connect before, this is my first time, but, I can't push anything because of that, how can I fix that?